# How to set layout height to one screen height except actionbar and status bar, in scrollview

Tags: android, layout, alignment, scrollview

I have a layout in a scrollview and I add another layout to the end of the first one. Actually I am trying to make a one page design and the rest of the other views will appear after scrolling. I tried to put linearlayout1 and linearlayout2 to another view but it didn't work. Also I set scrollview android:fillViewport="true" but it made the scrollview in screen size.

I've added an image of what I want, but it could also be one view, I mean lin1 and lin2 together.

I can set width and height for one phone but I want to do this for each screen. For example like yahoo weather app. They have done one layout for first view and start another view from the end of screen. I tried so many things but I couldn't imagine how to put layouts. Could you help me?

Thanks for your help

Here is what I want

[image: Here is what I want]

Here is I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:text="LinearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:text="LinearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp">

                <TextView
                    android:text="LnearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

But unfortunately I couldn't configure this for each screen size.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiLJ0.png)

Comment: Please provide your xml. I'm guessing you need to add match_parent height for your scrollview, but i cannot be sure without xml

Comment: I edited with xml and added one more image what I couldn't figure

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the height as in:

```
android:layout_height="250dp"
```

Set `android:layout_height="0dp"` and use

```
android:layout_weight="25"
```

And also in the other layout use weight. Weight works like this, if you have 3 components in your container, set the weights to let's say 1, 2 and 3 => they will take in that order 1/6, 2/6 and 3/6 of the container. 6 being the sum of 1,2,3. So here instead of using heights as 350 and 250, you can set them to 0 and use weights 2.5 and 3.5 or 25 and 35.

Comment: I proportioned with weight, it's ok but I want to set the first linearlayout height to one screen size, rest of views will be appear after I scroll?